# OS X 10.12 // Setting up mySQL server // JetBrains DataGrip

Tags: mysql, datagrip

I am a novice beginning to learn SQL. I have gone through tutorials on how to set up mySQL server, and am trying to use DataGrip as well. When I try to connect DataGrip to the mySQL server, it says my password has expired. (this is the password I received upon downloading and installing mySQL server).

I need to reset this password somehow, and have been trying to do so through the terminal. The tutorials I have tried do not help. I have been trying to access

```
    mysql>
```

using

```
    mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

while active as the superuser. However, I receive

```
    mysqld_safe : command not found
```

I have also gone into

```
    nano ~/.bash_profile
```

to add

```
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

I apologize if this all sounds incoherent, but any help would be great!!

Answer (score 1):

mysqld_safe - not installed any more on MacOS and some Linux as well - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html

on MacOS (in example case Sierra, MySQL 5.7)

You can edit (create and edit) - /etc/my.cnf

```
sudo nano /etc/my.cnf

[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables=true
```

than restart mysql (System preference)

than just run - mysql without any parameters